# How to import custom css and js in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using a custom theme for my app in ionic. But it has some css and javascript dependencies except bootstrap. 
Could you help me how can I import these libraries to my app?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are probably missing some Angular usage theory if you are trying to import Bootstrap into your project.

It uses a specific set of classes and they aren't out-of-the-box compatible with Angular / Ionic.

Ionic will give you a cross-device baseline set of styles so you should really work with Ionic to build upon their styles rather trying to fight it with another system.

However, to answer your questions:

### Importing CSS

You can edit app.scss and reference files in your imported packages like this:

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons';
```

Notice the `~` at the start and then the package name, then the path to the file. You don't need to put the .css or .scss on the end but you can if you want to.

### Importing JS

I'm not sure the best way to do this, but you can include scripts in the `<head>` tag by editing the `index.html`.

It's not something that's really done though and sounds like you are misunderstanding the way Angular / Ionic works.

It's based around building web components and you let Angular manage the actual live html. Your code that you write is TypeScript and its to interact with various API's that set the data model and then you let Angular generate the actual script.

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks for your reply. I solved css import problems on index.html and angular.json pages. But still I can't solve js imports. Ionic not show any errors while project is running on chrome but functions of js libraries' not working

Answer (score 0):

There is library for loading asynchronous JavaScript files. https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs

Install the package:

```
npm i scriptjs
```

Then use it anywhere like below:

```
import { get } from 'scriptjs';

ngOnInit() {

    get("assets/js/searchEmp.js", () => {
        getSerchInspContext = this;
        loadSearchEmp();
    });}`
```

OR

You can simply use the jquery method to append or remove the script tag in your header.

To add .js file, call below line under ngOnInit():

```
$('head').append('<script async src="assets/js/search.js"></script>');
```

Remove .js file:

```
document.querySelector('script[src="assets/js/search.js"]').remove();
```